# C++ - controlling a serial port - code won't compile

Tags: c++, serial-port, compiler-errors

I am trying to get an LED connected to a serial port to light up. I have followed a step-by-step tutorial which can be found [here](http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf). I have followed the directions exactly but cannot get the code to compile. From the PDF guide, it is part 2 which does not compile, which I reproduce here:

```
//<Set serial port parameters>

  DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
  dcbSerial.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
  if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
  {
  //error getting state
  }
  dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_19200;
  dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
  dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
  dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
  if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
  {
  //error setting serial port state
  }

//</Set serial port parameters>
```

I have included  in the code as specified, but I receive the error message "`dcbSerial' undeclared (first use this function)". I am using Dev-C++.

Essentially all I am trying to do is get a command which flashes the LED on and off, which I can put into another program I have (an eye tracking device - the idea is to get the LED to flash when your eyes are looking at it).

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `dcbSerial` with `dcbSerialParams`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Should have noticed this myself - I assumed the guide would have been flawless! Very new to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
dcbSerial.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
```

should be:

```
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
```

Really, you are going to have to put a bit more effort into reading and understanding compiler error messages - that one was about as clear as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a variable with name `dcbSerialParams`, but refer to it as `dcbSerial`

```
DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
dcbSerial.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
```